# Parse PDF text as CSV using the cordinate array

Tags: javascript, pdf.js, pdf-parsing

I have a input file as below which has digitized OCR text

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mAzjcHKX1tsKhNvTtF8InhkXFZbmdbKz?usp=sharing

This PDF has person details starting from page3

The expected output is to based on the certain locations
I am trying to accomplish using the array of zones of PDF locations since all of pages have text at same zones

The expected output array is
"1","1YO6963656","व वनिता सुनील भोईर',"तीचे नाव. सुनील भोईर","घर क्रमांक", "32 लिंग:महिला"
...
...

I have tried with

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.12.313/pdf.min.js" integrity="sha512-qa1o08MA0596eSNsnkRv5vuGloSKUhY09O31MY2OJpODjUVlaL0GOJJcyt7J7Z61FiEgHMgBkH04ZJ+vcuLs/w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.12.313/pdf.worker.min.js" integrity="sha512-S9Dwzi4TCjPQkxlaXsqQLj2gXUjPZk4HBzE7zWU6Itc1r2RNmlBrVLH4EsYQrdnzLgvkN8P7l9SCru+2I4rZwg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<label for="myfile">Select a file:</label>
<input type="file" id="file" name="file">



<script>
/*Offical release of the pdfjs worker*/
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.5.207/pdf.worker.js';

document.getElementById('file').onchange = function(event) {
  separator = ' '
  var file = event.target.files[0];
  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = function() {
    var typedarray = new Uint8Array(this.result);
    console.log(typedarray);

    let pdf = pdfjsLib.getDocument(typedarray);
    return pdf.promise.then(function(pdf) { // get all pages text
        let maxPages = pdf._pdfInfo.numPages;
        let countPromises = []; // collecting all page promises
        for (let i = 1; i <= maxPages; i++) {
            let page = pdf.getPage(i);
            countPromises.push(page.then(function(page) { // add page promise
                let textContent = page.getTextContent();
                return textContent.then(function(text) { // return content promise
                    return text.items.map(function(obj) {
                        return obj.str;
                    }).join(separator); // value page text
                });
            }));
        };

        return Promise.all(countPromises).then(function(texts) {
            for(let i = 0; i < texts.length; i++){
                texts[i] = texts[i].replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
            };
            console.log(texts)
            alert(texts)
            return texts;
        });
    });
  }
  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}

</script>
```